# Create array from string instruction

Tags: php

I can create array like this: `$array = ['key'=>'value'];`

But is possible to create array from string: 
`$string = '['key'=>'value']'? 
$array = $string` or `$array = (array) $string` does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by creating array from string? There is no such thing as a string array in PHP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```
$string = '[\'key\'=>\'value\']';
$array = eval('return '.$string.';');
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

try eval.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
$array = "['key'=>'value']";
$array = '$array = ' . $array;
eval($array);
```

But I wouldn't recommend exec as it could be unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Without eval():

```
$str = "['key'=>'value', 'key2'=>'value2']";
$ar = array();

foreach(explode(',', preg_replace('/[^\d\w,>]/', "", $str)) as $k => $v) {
    $tmp = explode('>', $v);
    $ar[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1]; 
}

var_dump($ar);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(5) "value"
  ["key2"]=>
  string(6) "value2"
}
```